# Erro "cannot find symbol" ao criar um objeto

Tags: java

Estou tentando instanciar um novo objeto "Caneta" na classe principal, mas está dando um erro: "Cannot find symbol".

- Classe principal(Aula02):

```
//pasta em que o código está inserido
package aula02;

//a classe DEVE ser escrita em maiúscula
public class Aula02 {
    
    //Classe principal:
    public static void main(String[] args){

        //instanciando o objeto Caneta
        Caneta c1 = new Caneta();
        //adicionando um estado ao atributo cor 
        c1.cor = "Azul";
        //f após o valor -> número real
        c1.ponta = 0.5f;
        c1.tampada = false;

    }

}
```

Devido ao "package aula02;", os dois códigos estão na mesma pasta.

- Classe Caneta:

```
//pasta em que se encontra o código
package aula02;

//Declaração da classe
public class Caneta{

    //Declarando os atributos da classe
    String modelo;
    String cor;
    float ponta;
    int carga;
    boolean tampada;
    
    //metódos da classe Caneta
    void status() {
        System.out.println("Uma caneta" + this.cor);
    }

    void rabiscar() {
    }

    void tampar() {

    }

    void destampar(){

    }

}
```

- Mensagem de erro:

```
Aula02.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
        Caneta c1 = new Caneta();
        ^
  symbol:   class Caneta
  location: class Aula02
Aula02.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
        Caneta c1 = new Caneta();
                        ^
  symbol:   class Caneta
  location: class Aula02
2 errors
```

Além disso, compilei a "classe Caneta" antes da classe principal e continua aparecendo o mesmo erro. Alguém pode me dizer como resolver esse problema?

Comment: Segui exatamente esses passos: criei os 2 arquivos, compilei `javac aula02/Caneta.java` e depois `javac aula02/Aula02.java` e funcionou. Talvez o problema seja a forma como vc tentou compilar (foi na linha de comando? usou alguma ferramenta? como tentou compilar? etc). Pior é a resposta aceita abaixo, que não faz sentido, pois se duas classes estão no mesmo pacote, não precisa de `import` (ou seja, precisaria saber exatamente como vc está compilando, pois esta é a causa do problema - usar `import` no mesmo pacote é uma gambiarra desnecessária, o ideal é corrigir a causa de fato)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Você deve importar a classe `Caneta` no arquivo da classe `Aula02`:

```
package aula02;

import aula02.Caneta;

public class Aula02 {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: _Importei a classe e no VSCode deu o seguinte erro:_                                 
`Aula02.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
import aula02.Caneta;
             ^
  symbol:   class Caneta
  location: package aula02
Aula02.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
        Caneta c1 = new Caneta();
        ^
  symbol:   class Caneta
  location: class Aula02
Aula02.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
        Caneta c1 = new Caneta();
                        ^
  symbol:   class Caneta
  location: class Aula02
3 errors`.

Answer (score -3):

confere no VSCode se tanto o arquivo Aula02.java quanto o arquivo Caneta.java estão no Package aula02. Não precisa dar o `import aula02.Caneta;` pois eles teoricamente estão no mesmo Package.